# Java regex (?i) vs Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, regex

I'm using `"\\b(\\w+)(\\W+\\1\\b)+"` along with `input = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1");` to find duplicate words in a string and remove the duplicates. For example the string input = "for for for" would become "for".

However it is failing to turn "Hello hello" into "Hello" even though I have used  `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

I can correct it by using `"(?i)\\b(\\w+)(\\W+\\1\\b)+"` but I want to know why this is necessary? Why do I have to use the (?i) flag when I have already specified Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE?

Heres the full code for clarity:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DuplicateWords {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\W+\\1\\b)+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numSentences = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    while (numSentences-- > 0) {
        String input = in.nextLine();

        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        // Check for subsequences of input that match the compiled pattern
        while (m.find()) {
            input = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
        }

        // Prints the modified sentence.
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining a regex with `CASE_SENSITIVE` flag but not using it correctly in `replaceAll` method.

You can also use `(?i)` in the middle of the regex for ignore case match of back-reference `\1` like this:

```
String repl = "Hello hello".replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)(\\W+(?i:\\1)\\b)+", "$1");
//=> Hello
```

And then use `Matcher.replaceAll` later.

**Working Code:**

```
public class DuplicateWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\W+(?i:\\1)\\b)+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

        // OR this one also works
        // String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\W+\\1\\b)+";
        // Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numSentences = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        while (numSentences-- > 0) {
            String input = in.nextLine();

            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

            // Check for subsequences of input that match the compiled pattern
            if (m.find()) {
                input = m.replaceAll("$1");
            }

            // Prints the modified sentence.
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So (?i) only effects the block immediately after it (In this case \\1) and not the whole regex?

Comment: I still don't understand why I have to use (?i) at all. Should'nt Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE be sufficient?

Comment: In your example, placing `(?i)` mid-regex has the same effect as placing it at the start, which is the same as using `CASE_INSENSITIVE`, because the captured group is case insensitive. A better example would be something like `([ABC])(?i)\1`, which is different from `(?i)([ABC])\1`

Comment: Check my updated answer and correct way to use `replaceAll` with a `Pattern/Matcher`