# (?i) regex - Where in expression?

Tags: java, regex

new to regex.
[In one of the comments to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471321/java-regex-i-vs-pattern-case-insensitive): it mentions that (?i) can be in the middle of the expression and still function correctly. Please explain why it works in example 3 but not in 1 and 2. Does the case insensitivity only apply to what follows after?

eg 1 - false:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("t(h(?i)e).*","tHe foo"));
```

eg 2 - false:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("th(?i)e.*","tHe foo"));
```

eg 3 - true:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("t(?i)he.*","tHe foo"));
```

Comment: Indeed `(?i)` modifier in the middle of regex affects only the pattern that comes after this i.e. on right hand side.

Comment: Look at the top answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145659/what-do-i-and-i-in-regex-mean `(?i)` **starts** the case insensitive. So in your cases, since the string to check has an uppercase H, patterns 1 to 3 fail because they only match against lowercase 'h'.

Comment: Note (for my own OCD), you have two identical "example 1".

Comment: The only exception I know is the python re module. Whatever the position you put it, it affects all the pattern.

Comment: @Mena To be fair, they're also both titled "eg 1" :D

Comment: @AntonH I know! Still gives me the shivers :D